# Moving Android Studio (Settings) to another Computer

Tags: android, eclipse, visual-studio, android-studio, settings

Please don't confuse this with moving Android Studio Projects.

I'm about to buy a Surface Pro 3 (i7 or i5) for college and to program with IDEs. I have a laptop that I am currently using. It has all my Git (BitBucket) settings, shortcut preferences, UI look and much more. I don't want to set this up again because of how long it took me to set all this up (Sum total of days). I was just wondering if I could export the settings by flash drive or a folder I could just copy to the new Laptop and BAM!!! everything was as I left it.

I know I can do this with Eclipse but not sure for Android Studio. Thanks for help.

Separate but kind of the same::

I was just wondering if I could use the same SDK Folder with all the API, Tools and Extras for both Eclipse and Android Studio. I used to use Eclipse until I found out recently that Google would soon stop supporting Eclipse IDE for Android. I have very complicated projects in my Eclipse IDE so I can't export them to Android Studio or I would have.

So I was just wondering if it would be safe to use the same SDK folder for Eclipse and Android... OH!!! and Visual Studio 2015 (I wanna start messing with this since you can now use this to program Android Apps with C#)

Comment: Have you tried File > Export Settings and File > Import Settings?

Comment: @hoomi Bro!!! Thanks for this, I checked and that's exactly what I need, I just started using Android-Studio about a week ago. So I don't know much about its features

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the option `File > Export Settings` on your old laptop and then save it to a jar file.

Then copy the jar file over to your new laptop and then use a`File > Import Settings` to import the jar file.

Comment: will this export everything?Sdks etc

Comment: No, SDK is not included.

Comment: With AndroidStudio 4.x (Bumblebee) and above, it is 'File > Manage IDE Settings > Import Settings' & 'File > Manage IDE Settings > Import Settings'

Answer (score 1):

You can move/backup it manually using tutorial of changing [android studio settings location](https://practical-start.blogspot.com.eg/2016/12/changing-android-studio-settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best option to share AS settings is using **IntelijIdea** [settings repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-settings-repository.html)

The feature is supported by Android Studio. You may create and attach this git repository to any IDE copy and every workstation.
The local/remote settings are synced automatically.

On the other hand, a particular project settings should be shared by using a `git tree`. Modify `project` settings profile by adjusting your team's code style conventions, for example. Then do not ignore `.idea/codeStyles` folder and share it with git.

Other team members after cloning/sync should also switch code style to `project`.